# Flat-Band Basis (Bernevig & Hughes) for computation of Hall conductance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators

In Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors (Bernevig & Hughes) a limit of an insulating Hamiltonian, the flat-band limit is used to compute the Hall conductance. For the fist we define the adiabatic deformation of the bands (the chemical potential is located between $\varepsilon_{p}$ and $\varepsilon_{p+1}$ bands):
$$ E_{i}(k,t) = \varepsilon_{i}(k)(1-t)+\varepsilon_{G}t, \;\;\;\; 1\leq i \leq p$$
$$ E_{i}(k,t) = \varepsilon_{i}(k)(1-t)+\varepsilon_{E}t, \;\;\;\; p< i \leq m$$
So at the end ($t=1$) we have only two flat bands and we use them to calculate the Hall conductance. The essential moment is that the eigenstates are the same i.e. they aren't change during the transformation. But could this be done? The eigenstate is connected with eigenvalue, so if we change
the last the eigenstate **must** change and we cannot define such transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  is no different than considering a Hamiltonian whose   matrix  is diagonal with entries $E_i(k,t=0)$ and keeping the matrix diagonal while the entries change to $E_i(k,t)$. The eigenstates $(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$, $ (0,1,\ldots,0)^T$ *etc*, do not change.